# How do I conditionally format a cell based on a date within a string of text?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, conditional-formatting

Suppose today is 13 October 2015. I want to apply conditional formatting rules to four cells in Google Sheets:

Cell 1:

> 10/22 Remove cat from bookcase

Cell 2:

> 10/23 Put books back

Cell 3:

> 10/24 Repair bookcase, 11/2 Send cat to vet

Cell 4:

> 12/6 Sell cat

Cell 1 should be formatted one way ([first] date is before today), Cell 2 should be formatted a second way ([first] date is today), Cell 3 should be formatted a third way (first date is tomorrow) and Cell 4 ([first] date is not within the last week, today nor tomorrow).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
=datevalue(regexextract(A1, "[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}"))
```

extracts the first date-looking part from a string and interprets it as a date (if this is possible according to the current locale's convention; "13/2 buy a dog" will throw an error).

You can then set multiple rules with custom formulas involving the comparison of the above with `today()`:

Before today:

```
=datevalue(regexextract(A1, "[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}")) < today()
```

Today:

```
=datevalue(regexextract(A1, "[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}")) = today()
```

Tomorrow:

```
=datevalue(regexextract(A1, "[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}")) = today()+1
```

Not within last week, today or tomorrow:

```
=or(datevalue(regexextract(A1, "[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}")) < today()-7, datevalue(regexextract(A1, "[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}")) > today()+1)
```

Comment: I'm getting a VALUE error with datevalue; U.S. spreadsheet. (RegEx works like a charm. Thank you.)

Comment: The issue I found was resolved by changing "datavalue" with an "a" at the end of "data" with "datevalue"presenting an "e" at the end of "date".

Comment: Whoops, a typo. Corrected.

Comment: would you please share the link of the sheet so that I could understand the way of applying the rule. This is really helpful rule i was actually looked for. Thanks in advance.